# State hook change not re-rendering parent component when state updated from child

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, parent-child, react-props

I have a Parent and a child component. The child component is a pop-up rendered based on parent state value props. the child component is a pop-up that renders perfectly on the initial message from the server, and it changes the state of the parent props when the pop-up is closed.

However, when a secondary message comes from the server, the pop-up is not re-rendered a second time.

The child component is basically being show/hide based on a boolean that's triggered when there's a message from the server. Closing the child changes the state back to the original value. However, when a second message comes, the child component does not re-render.

I'm new to React, how do I solve this problem?

***Parent:***

```
export default function App() {
  var [props, setProps] = useState(false)

  const PropsToFalse = async () => {
    var test = props
    setProps(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('http://10.0.2.2:7008/ChatHub')
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build()

      newConnection
        .start()
        .then(async () => {
          await newConnection.send('AddToGroupLogin', category, email, loc)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })

      newConnection.on('receivemessage', (message) => {
        var test = props
        setProps(true)
      })
    })
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TabTwoScreen props={props} setProps={PropsToFalse}></TabTwoScreen>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Child:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import { Button } from './Button'
import { Modal } from './Modal'

export default function TabTwoScreen(props: any) {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = React.useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkForSubscription = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsModalVisible(() => !isModalVisible)
    }, 1500)
    return () => clearTimeout(checkForSubscription)
  }, [])

  const handleSignUp = () => {
    // sign up the user and close the modal
    setIsModalVisible(() => !isModalVisible)
    props.setProps()
  }

  const handleDecline = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(() => !isModalVisible)
    props.setProps()
  }

  return props.props ? (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <Text style={styles.title}>Premium stuff here</Text> */}
      <View style={styles.separator} />
      <Modal isVisible={isModalVisible}>
        <Modal.Container>
          <View style={styles.modal}>
            <Modal.Header title="You're just one step away!" />
            <Modal.Body>
              <Text style={styles.text}>
                Want to answer this persons request?!
              </Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="email"
                keyboardType="email-address"
              />
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <View style={styles.button}>
                <Button title="No thanks" onPress={handleDecline} />
                <Button title="Lets go!" onPress={handleSignUp} />
              </View>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </View>
        </Modal.Container>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  ) : ""
  )
}
```

Comment: Try `props.setProps(false)`.

Comment: I tried both using setProps state and PropsToFalse helper function. Both of them correctly change the value of parent props to false for the re-render. However, when the value changes to true from server response, the re-render for child (popup) never happens.

Comment: I think there's an issue on your return on the useEffect, it will trigger once and rendered once. Did you try to separate the return component on the body? 
you need also to add a [] on the useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

you must pass `setProps` to child, as below:

```
<TabTwoScreen props={props} setProps={setProps}>
```

on child component just call

```
setProps && setProps(your params)
```